# an integral which results only in $C$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am currently studying integration. Out of curiosity a question came to my mind.

Does there exist any indefinite integral which results only in a constant. For example, all the terms cancel like ones in a telescoping series.

Of course $0x$ is one such example. Something at first look not equal to $0$ but due to some properties of elementary functions.

Comment: The integral is an antiderivative. Now, if $F(x)=C$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$, then, $f(x)= C'=0$.

Comment: Yes i have mentioned it . just wanted to know if theres another example excluding $0$

Comment: There isn't another.

Comment: It must be the derivative of a constant function, i.e. it MUST be $0$. The zero function is unique, don't you think?

Comment: I edited to fix some grammar and help with readability. Feel free to rollback if it does not reflect the intent of your question.

Comment: Okay no problem